# Deserialize Json into C#

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I got some Json, that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "starttime": "2020-02-27T14:30:00Z",
    "endtime": "2020-02-27T14:40:00Z"
  },
  {
    "Temp": {
      "value": 3
    },
    "Pressure": {
      "value": 29
    },
    "Humidity": {
      "value": 85
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to deserialize it onto a object on the form:

```
public class Sample {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

and then get 3 instances where name is set to either Temp, Pressure, Humidity, and Value set to 3, 29, 85
I don't really care about the start-/endtime part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

/Søren

Update:

Came up with this myself:

```
var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(content);

var samples = tmp.
    SelectMany(x => ((JToken) x).Children())
    .Where(x => !((JProperty) x).Name.Contains("time"))
    .Select(x =>
    {
        var tmp2 = x.First.ToObject<Sample>();
        tmp2.name = ((JProperty) x).Name;
        return tmp2;
    })
    .ToList();
```

but I think Pavel's solution below, is more readable....

Comment: If you're using the latest version of .NET Core then there's now a built-in library to do this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to   -- Otherwise, for older versions of .NET, get the `Newtonsoft.Json` library from NuGet - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Json.Linq`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to get a list of `Sample` objects from your json. Parse json to [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) instance, then enumerate all properties of the last object to get the names and values

```cs
var array = JArray.Parse(json);

var samples = ReadSamples(array.Last());
foreach (var sample in samples)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{sample.Name} {sample.Value}");
}

IEnumerable<Sample> ReadSamples(JToken data)
{
    foreach (JProperty item in data)
    {
        yield return new Sample()
        {
            Name = item.Name,
            Value = item.Value["value"]?.Value<int>() ?? 0
        };
    }
}
```

The output will be the following

```
Temp 3
Pressure 29
Humidity 85
```

It's also possible to do the same using [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) API, which is available from .NET Core 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Per your posted JSON, you would get a model like below. Use http://json2csharp.com/#

```
public class Temp
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Pressure
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Humidity
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public DateTime starttime { get; set; }
    public DateTime endtime { get; set; }
    public Temp Temp { get; set; }
    public Pressure Pressure { get; set; }
    public Humidity Humidity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And for smolesen: the point here is - use something like the above to interpret the data, then write code to reshape it into a model of your preferred shape afterwards

Comment: There's really no need to use that website: Visual Studio (and other IDEs) have a "paste JSON as classes" feature built in; put JSON in the clipboard, and let the IDE generate types that work with it. Similarly for XML too.

Comment: I think most of you is missing the point, that the number of types (Temp, Pressure, Humidity) can change dynamically, and I don't want to go change the code each time a new "type" is added., That's also why my datasample class is generic, with a name/type property.

Comment: @smolesen It wasn't clear from the question. Why do you think two of the three answers suggested using classes? The title of the question also simply says *Deserialize Json into C#*, which is vague. We don't *know* that you need a dynamic solution unless you specifiy that in the question. As helpful as SO is, at the end of the day we can't read minds.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is not dynamic, creating classes which model your JSON is a good idea.

An easy way is to **Copy JSON to clipboard -> Open Visual Studio -> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes**.

This should give you the following classes:

```
public class Class1
{
    public DateTime starttime { get; set; }
    public DateTime endtime { get; set; }
    public Temp Temp { get; set; }
    public Pressure Pressure { get; set; }
    public Humidity Humidity { get; set; }
}

public class Temp
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Pressure
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Humidity
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can deserialize the JSON array to `List<Class1>`using the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) NuGet package:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

string json = @"[
  {
    ""starttime"": ""2020 - 02 - 27T14: 30:00Z"",
    ""endtime"": ""2020-02-27T14:40:00Z""
  },
  {
    ""Temp"": {
      ""value"": 3
    },
    ""Pressure"": {
      ""value"": 29
    },
    ""Humidity"": {
      ""value"": 85
    }
  }
]";

var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(json);
```

Comment: The idea was to NOT have a class for each type (since I don't know the number of types)

Comment: @smolesen Hence why I said this solution is only suitable for non dynamic JSON.